# How to limit mongoose find response to show objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So Here's my code :

```
router.get('/list/all',(req, res, next) => {
    Order.find((err, result) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        result: result._id //Doesn't work
      });
    });
  });
```

I want my api to return only `ObjectIds`.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you `console.log(result)` do you get any data?

Comment: @ShivamSood Yes it returns all the data. But I only need the ObjectIds. What should I do?

Comment: You probably need to convert the result (which is `Document` by default) to `object` using `result=result.toObject()`

Comment: @ShivamSood I'm pretty sure that is not the right way.

Comment: Yup this will work but a `hacky` way, using `.lean()` is better

Comment: By Show ObjectId, do you mean show only _id field?

Comment: @hamedjvh `find()` will give you an array response, just check `console.log(result[0]._id)`, and you should set projection for only _ids `Order.find({}, {_id: 1}, (err, result) => {` this will result only _ids for all records but in array. and just return `result: result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), `.find` accepts these parameters:

> Parameters:
>
> - filter «Object|ObjectId»
> - [projection] «Object|String» optional fields to return, see Query.prototype.select()
> - [options] «Object» optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()
> - [callback] «Function»

So you can set `_id` to `1` on the projection and it will only return `_id` field

```js
Order.find({}, { _id: 1}, (err, result) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        result
      });
);
```